# Por que me devuelve un array vacio?

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber si es que me podrian ayudar a resolver este problema que tengo. La cosa es que cree una clase en javascript con la cual paso un array y una fecha por el constructor. La cosa es que ciertos de esta clase me devuelven un array vacio y no se porque, ya que use esos mismos metodos en otros archivos y funcionan bien
Esta es la clase que utilizo para manejar el array que tengo

```
class DataModule {
    constructor(events, currentDate) {
        this.events = events;
        this.currentDate = currentDate;
    }
    getAll() {
        return this.events;
    }
    getUpcoming() {
        return this.events.filter((event) => event.date > this.currentDate);
    }
    getPast() {
        return this.events.filter((event) => event.date < this.currentDate);
    }
    getPercent(total, assistance) {
        return ((assistance * 100) / total).toFixed(2);
    }
    getEventsWithPercent() {
        return this.events
            .filter((event) => event.assistance)
            .map((event) => ({
                name: event.name,
                percentAssistance: this.getPercent(event.capacity, event.assistance),
            }))
            .sort((a, b) => b.percentAssistance - a.percentAssistance);
    }
    getEventsWithCapacity() {
        return this.events.map((event) => ({
            name: event.name,
            capacity: event.capacity,
        }))
    .sort((a, b) => b.capacity - a.capacity);
    }
    getHighestPercentEvent() {
        return this.getEventsWithPercent()[0].name;
    }
    getLowestPercentEvent() {
        return this.getEventsWithPercent()[this.getEventsWithPercent().length - 1].name;
    }
    eventRevenue(assistance, price) {
        return price * assistance;
    }
    getUpcomingEventsStatics() {
        return this.getUpcoming().map((event) => ({
            name: event.name,
            revenue: this.eventRevenue(
                event.estimate,
                event.price
            ),
            percentAssistance: this.getPercent(
                event.capacity,
                event.estimate
            ),
        }));
    }
    getPastEventsStatics() {
        return this.getPast().map((event) => ({
            name: event.name,
            revenue: this.eventRevenue(
                event.assistance,
                event.price
            ),
            percentAssistance: this.getPercent(
                event.capacity,
                event.assistance
            ),
        }));
    }
}
```

Y este es el modulo desde el cual lo estoy llamando

```
import DataModule from '../module/dataModule.js'
import getData from '../module/getData.js'
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  const firstTable = document.getElementsByClassName('first-table')[0]
  const upcomingTable = document.getElementById('upcoming-table')
  const pastTable = document.getElementById('past-table')
  const data = await getData("https://amazing-events.onrender.com/api/events")
  const eventsModule = new DataModule(data.events, data.currentValue)
  const highestPercentEvent = eventsModule.getHighestPercentEvent()
  const lowestPercentEvent = eventsModule.getLowestPercentEvent()
  const largestCapacity = eventsModule.getEventsWithCapacity()[0].name
  const upcomingStatics = eventsModule.getUpcomingEventsStatics() // Devuelve un array vacio
  const pastStatics = eventsModule.getPastEventsStatics() // devuelve un array vacio
  console.log(eventsModule.getAll()) // devuelve todos los elementos
  console.log(eventsModule.getPast()) // devuelve un array vacio
})
```

He probado en otros controladores que tengo de la web, y estos mismos metodos que me devuelven un array vacio funcionan perfectamente. Quiero saber si alguien me ayudaria y me explicaria que esta pasando para poder solucionarlo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Habra algun problema con las fechas? tenes ejemplos de datos?

Comment: Si este mismo código funciona en otras partes, la culpa debe ser de lo que está cambiando... los datos. Asegúrate de que los datos que le pasas en este controller específico tengan el formato adecuado.

Comment: Donde pones: `new DataModule(data.events, data.currentValue)` ¿no será: `new DataModule(data.events, data.currentDate)`?

Comment: Claro, es **.currentDate**, no me habia dado cuenta. Muchas gracias

Comment: 1. ¿Has probado a ver que te devuelve getUpcoming()? Podría ayudar si devuelve otra cosa que no sea vacío. 2. ¿Has comprobado la fecha que introduces? Quizás no se pueda comparar porque introduces una fecha no válida o vacía,o en otro formato, diferente al que se compara (por ejemplo en España tenemos 20/12/2022 y en USA es 2022/12/20). Creo que el problema viene de la fecha, ya que si al devolverlos todos te da los eventos, eso quiere decir que donde falla es al comparar la fecha con los eventos a devolver.

Comment: @FranciscoJavier deberías poner eso como respuesta

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No lo he puesto como respuesta porque me ha parecido que se trata de un simple "gazapo" del OP...